# Problems in using Python and BeautifulSoup to parse HTML page avoiding Java

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling with the parsing of a website that contains some Java: using BeautifulSoup I should be able to extract the informations that I need, but despite all my trials I can't understand how. Unfortunately I can't post the link because it's a restricted website, but I can post the HTML code and the results I get, hoping that someone could help me.

Here's an extract of the HTML:

```html
<table class="customer-info-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Nome</label>
      XXXXXX XXXX
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Cognome</label>
      XXXXXXX
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Codice cliente</label>
      N/A
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Indirizzo e-mail</label>
      XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<span class="panel-headline">Commento articolo</span>
<hr/>
<i class="rating r1"></i><br/>
  BLACKLIST

<textarea name="text" id="review-text" rows="12" readonly="readonly">
Mi avete mandato e-mail Ke il prodotto era disponibile; invece è esaurito........... Mah.</textarea>

<span class="panel-headline">Commenti sulla vestibilità</span>
<hr/>
<table class="size-info-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Lunghezza</label>
      Viel zu kurz
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Larghezza</label>
      Viel zu eng
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Taglia</label>
      &nbsp
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Varianti</label>
      &nbsp
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Statura</label>
      &nbsp
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Rezensions-ID:</b>
        <span id="review-id">11166707</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>Creata:</b>
        <span class="utc-date">
          23.03.2018 12:23:15
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Letzte &Auml;nderung</b>
        <span class="utc-date">
          23.03.2018 12:23:15
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>di</b>
        Kunde
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Data pubblicazione:</b>
        <span class="utc-date">
          
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="span4">
        <div id="editing-functions-panel" class="label full-height">
            <span class="panel-headline">Modifica</span>
<hr/>
<div>
  <label>Scegli un destinatario</label>
  <a id="reset-recipients-list-link" class="btn-link" href="#" onclick="reviews.resetRecipientsList(true); return false;">Cancella la lista destinatari</a>
  <select name="email-recipients-select" id="email-recipients-select"><option value=""></option>
<option value="servizio@bonprix.it">XXXXXX@XXXXXXX.it</option></select>
  <textarea name="email-recipients-textarea" id="email-recipients-textarea">
</textarea>
  <a id="send-mail-btn" class="btn" data-confirm-translation-modified-text="Die Übersetzung wurde noch nicht gespeichert. Rezension trotzdem versenden?" href="#" onclick="reviews.sendMail(true); return false;">Invia recensione</a>
  <label>Traduci</label>
  <textarea name="text" id="review-uebersetzung">
</textarea>
  <label>Feedback al cliente</label>
  <textarea name="text" id="review-feedbackToCustomer">
</textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Tipo di recensione</label>
  <select name="meinungstyp" id="review-meinungstyp"><option selected="selected" value="R">Recensione</option>
<option value="G">Risposte</option>
<option value="A">Archivio</option></select>
</div>
<div id="aktiv-checkboxes-container">
  <div class="control-group use-bootstrap-groups">
    <label class="control-label" for="review_aktiv">Pubblicata</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="review_aktiv" id="review_aktiv" />
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="change-active-state btn " data-value="T" href="#">Sì</a>
        <a class="change-active-state btn " data-value="F" href="#">No</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid form-actions possible-multi-line">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" id="save-review-btn" remote="true" href="#" onclick="reviews.saveReview(true); return false;">Salva recensione</a>
  <a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-review-btn" remote="true" data-confirm-dialog-title="Cancella recensioni" href="#" onclick="reviews.deleteSelectedReview(true); return false;"><i class='icon-trash icon-white'></i> Cancella recensioni</a>
</div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div id="search-reviews-tab">  <div class="mini-statistics">
    <p>
      Da controllare: 88 / Pubblicata: 301941 / Non pubblicata: 9198 / Prenotate: [0], mie: [0]
    </p>
  </div>
```

I tried to run the following code (the variable page contains the results of a post request made on a form):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = response3.text
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')    
for table in soup2.find_all(["table", {"class": "customer-info-table"}]):
    string = table.get_text().replace("\\n", "").replace("\/th", "").replace("\/span", "").replace("\/i", "").replace("\/p", "").replace("\/a", "").replace("\/tr", "").replace("\/div", "").replace("\/td", "").replace("<\/tbody", "").replace("\/table", "").replace("\/textarea", "").replace("\/b","").replace("<\/label", "").replace("ead", "").replace("<>", "")
print string
```

That's what I get when I print string:

```
                                            1                Rezensionen 
gefunden                                                                                                  
5                                      Volevo sapere se rientrano perchè 
vedo che la taglia 48/50 è terminata ...                                                  
>                                            Informazioni articoloN. 
art.>97655395Masterstyle-ID>33426811Digistyle-ID>19163347Ø Media dei 
voti>4.13 Lunghezza>GiustoLarghezza>GiustoDisponibilità>Esaurito(0)                                        
Dati cliente            Nome>      XXXXXX              Cognome>      
XXXXXX                  Codice cliente>      N/A              Indirizzo 
e-mail>      XXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com      Commento articolo  
BLACKLISTVolevo sapere se rientrano perchè vedo che la taglia 48/50 è 
terminata ...Commenti sulla vestibilità            Lunghezza>      Viel 
zu kurz              Larghezza>      Viel zu eng              Taglia>                         Varianti>                     Statura>                                 
    Rezensions-ID:        9430069                    Creata:                  
    01.01.2017 12:37:16                                    Letzte 
    Änderung 05.01.2017 07:52:42                            di        
YYYYYYYY                            
Data pubblicazione:                                                                              
Modifica  Scegli un destinatario>  Cancella la lista destinatari  
<\/option>XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.it<\/option><\/select>    Invia recensione  
Traduci>    Feedback al cliente>    Tipo di recensione>  
Recensione<\/option>Risposte<\/option>Archivio<\/option><\/select>      
Pubblicata>                      Sì        No              Salva 
recensione   Cancella recensioni                    
').trigger('repaint');
reviews.initEditReviewTab();
$('#reviews-tab-navigation').tabs('option', 'active', 0);
$('.search-tab-buttons').html('              Cerca      Ricerca standard      
Statistiche      ');
$('.mini-statistics').replaceWith('            Da controllare: 90 / 
Pubblicata: 301968 / Non pubblicata: 9198 / Prenotate: [0], mie: [0]      
');

        Nome>      XXXXXXX              Cognome>      XXXXXXX                  
Codice cliente>      N/A              Indirizzo e-mail>      
XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com      Commento articolo  BLACKLISTVolevo sapere 
se rientrano perchè vedo che la taglia 48/50 è terminata ...Commenti 
sulla vestibilità            Lunghezza>      Viel zu kurz              
Larghezza>      Viel zu eng              Taglia>                     
Varianti>                     Statura>                                 
Rezensions-ID:        9430069                    Creata:                  
01.01.2017 12:37:16                                    Letzte Änderung                  
05.01.2017 07:52:42                            di        YYYYYYY                            
 Data pubblicazione:                                                                              
Modifica  Scegli un destinatario>  Cancella la lista destinatari  
<\/option>XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.it<\/option><\/select>    Invia recensione  
Traduci>    Feedback al cliente>    Tipo di recensione>  
Recensione<\/option>Risposte<\/option>Archivio<\/option><\/select>      
Pubblicata>                      Sì        No              Salva 
recensione   Cancella recensioni                    
').trigger('repaint');
reviews.initEditReviewTab();
$('#reviews-tab-navigation').tabs('option', 'active', 0);
$('.search-tab-buttons').html('              Cerca      Ricerca standard      
Statistiche      ');
$('.mini-statistics').replaceWith('            Da controllare: 90 / 
Pubblicata: 301968 / Non pubblicata: 9198 / Prenotate: [0], mie: [0]      
');

        Lunghezza>      Viel zu kurz              Larghezza>      Viel zu 
eng              Taglia>                     Varianti>                     
Statura>                                 Rezensions-ID:        9430069                    
Creata:                  01.01.2017 12:37:16                                    
Letzte Änderung                  05.01.2017 07:52:42                            
di        YYYYYY                            Data pubblicazione:                                                                              
Modifica  Scegli un destinatario>  Cancella la lista destinatari  
<\/option>XXXXXX@XXXXXX.it<\/option><\/select>    Invia recensione  
Traduci>    Feedback al cliente>    Tipo di recensione>  
Recensione<\/option>Risposte<\/option>Archivio<\/option><\/select>      
Pubblicata>                      Sì        No              Salva 
recensione   Cancella recensioni                    
').trigger('repaint');
reviews.initEditReviewTab();
$('#reviews-tab-navigation').tabs('option', 'active', 0);
$('.search-tab-buttons').html('              Cerca      Ricerca standard      
Statistiche      ');
$('.mini-statistics').replaceWith('            Da controllare: 90 / 
Pubblicata: 301968 / Non pubblicata: 9198 / Prenotate: [0], mie: [0]      
');

              Rezensions-ID:        9430069                    Creata:                  
01.01.2017 12:37:16                                    Letzte Änderung                  
05.01.2017 07:52:42                            di        YYYYYYY                            
Data pubblicazione:                                                                              
Modifica  Scegli un destinatario>  Cancella la lista destinatari  
<\/option>XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.it<\/option><\/select>    Invia recensione  
Traduci>    Feedback al cliente>    Tipo di recensione>  
Recensione<\/option>Risposte<\/option>Archivio<\/option><\/select>      
Pubblicata>                      Sì        No              Salva 
recensione   Cancella recensioni                    
').trigger('repaint');
reviews.initEditReviewTab();
$('#reviews-tab-navigation').tabs('option', 'active', 0);
$('.search-tab-buttons').html('              Cerca      Ricerca standard      
Statistiche      ');
$('.mini-statistics').replaceWith('            Da controllare: 90 / 
Pubblicata: 301968 / Non pubblicata: 9198 / Prenotate: [0], mie: [0]      
');

        Cerca      Ricerca standard      Statistiche      ');
$('.mini-statistics').replaceWith('            Da controllare: 90 / 
Pubblicata: 301968 / Non pubblicata: 9198 / Prenotate: [0], mie: [0]      
');
```

I can't understand why it repeats the contents several times: I need the informations just once, and by the way not all of them (just the first part of the first block of results, before  the "reviews.initEditReviewTab();").

Any idea or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the HTML snippet you provided is a good representation of the data that is causing your problem?  When I run your code on the snippet, it just returns the text from one set of contents (the last set), seems to work as intended.

Comment: What do you mean by "website that contains some Java" and also did you use "View page source"  option (in Chrome shortcut is Ctrl+U) to get HTML code or did you do something else?

Comment: @andrew_reece I thought that snippet was enough, but maybe then the problem is somewhere else in the previous HTML code. I'll check.

Comment: @ands sorry for my poor explanation: I used the "View source" option  to get the HTML snippet.

Comment: @Greenfox can you add these three lines to your code: `file = open('mypage.html', 'w')`, `file.write(page)`, `file.close()`. This will create html file with HTML that python scraped from web. Than you can open that file in text editor and compare HTML code to one you got from "View source" option.(You can use this [page](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) to compare code).

Comment: @ands thank you for the suggestion, I did it. At the same time I found a workaround, not very elegant but useful for my purposes: for table in soup2.find_all(["table", {"class": "customer-info-table"}], limit=1):  with limit=1 I get the resuts just once